# UIPasteboardChanged notification not called in Universal Clipboard

Tags: ios, iphone, macos

With Universal Clipboard I was expecting that the UIPasteboardChanged notification could be called when an user does a copy from the iMac (or Macbook) and has the app in foreground. Is there any way to catch this event?